# How to disable the angularJS routing system

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have a project developed in angular 1, I am using routeProvider and locationProvider. But now that the project is "ready", I need to deactivate the route system, that is, when the URL changes, when I go to another page, I need the page reloaded.

Has anyone ever had to do this?

Here is the route system I use on the routes.js of the pages:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
.module('solicitardocumentos')
.config(Config);

function Config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/solicitardocumentos', {
        templateUrl: 'modulosolicitardocumentos/template/index.html',
        controller: 'solicitardocumentosController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

}
})();
```